# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I get an error trying to pass a IQueryable to a view that needs an IEnumerable. I either need to convert the IQueryable to an IEnumerable or change my view to accept and use the IQueryable.
What I don't get is if I get the contents both a table and a query are lists. It shouldn't be that difficult to work with.

Here is my controller:

```
    namespace OASIS_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class MainsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db3;
        public MainsController(ApplicationDbContext db3)
        {
            _db3 = db3;

        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Biredat2> objList = (from m in _db3.biredat2
                                             join s in _db3.suivi on m.Reseau equals s.Reseau
                                             join sa in _db3.Sub_action on m.Reseau equals sa.reseau into _sa
                                             from x in _sa.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                             select m);

            return NewMethod(objList);
        }

        private IActionResult NewMethod(IEnumerable<Biredat2> objList)
        {
            return View(objList);
        }
    }

    // GET: Biredats
  
}


Here is the view (just put the first field for clarity)

    @model IEnumerable<OASIS_MVC.Models.AnalysteMain>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Anal_Main";
}

<h1>Anal_Main</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Envelope)
        </th>
```

Here is the model (just put the first few fields for clarity)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

#nullable disable

namespace OASIS_MVC.Models
{
    public partial class AnalysteMain
    {
        [Key]
        public int Reseau { get; set; }
        public string Envelope { get; set; }
        public string Nom_Envelope { get; set; }
        public string Bam { get; set; }
```

Here is the full view!

```
@model List<OASIS_MVC.Models.AnalysteMain>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Anal_Main";
}

<h1>Anal_Main</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reseau)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Envelope)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nom_Envelope)
            </th>
```

I've added the Biredat2 class here  ( Just the top portion! )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

#nullable disable

namespace OASIS_MVC.Models
{
    public partial class Biredat2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int Reseau { get; set; }
        public string Envelope { get; set; }
        public string Nom_Envelope { get; set; }
```

Comment: Here is the complete error code!                                                     
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[OASIS_MVC.Models.Biredat2]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[OASIS_MVC.Models.AnalysteMain]'.

Comment: I see the data in DATA is good and contains exactly what I wanted in my joins. I just can't figure out how to pass the info as an ienumerable to the view.  The other thing that bothers me is this line in the error code [OASIS_MVC.Models.Biredat2] as it picks that up from the select m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to fix the action

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
var objList = (from m in _db3.biredat2
  join s in _db3.suivi on m.Reseau equals s.Reseau
 join sa in _db3.Sub_action on m.Reseau equals sa.reseau into _sa
  from sa in _sa.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new AnalysteMain {
    Reseau = s.Reseau,
    Envelope =
    Nom_Envelope =
    Bam =
 }

  ).ToList();

  return view(objList);
        }
```

I left empty properties, because you didn't publish any classes.

and by the way it would be better if you change your model to list too

```
 @model List<OASIS_MVC.Models.AnalysteMain>
```

you will need it  soon as far I can see it now already. Fix the view

```
@if(Model!=null && Model.Count>0)
{
table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Reseau)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Envelope)
        </th>
          ........
```

Comment: Did the changes but now I get another type of error. 'List<AnalysteMain>' does not contain a definition for 'Reseau' and no accessible extension method 'Reseau' accepting a first argument of type 'List<AnalysteMain>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) OASIS_MVC C:\programming\Oasis\OASIS_MVC\Views\Mains\Index.cshtml 16 Active

Comment: I have to see the whole Index view

Comment: Its too large to fit. I'll cut it down by eliminating fields but keep the logic.

Comment: Just show the line that gives the exeption then

Comment: Reseau ,Envelope and Nom_Envelope all have red lines .......    @model List<OASIS_MVC.Models.AnalysteMain>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Anal_Main";
}

<h1>Anal_Main</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reseau)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Envelope)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nom_Envelope)

Comment: How do you add code formatting in a comment?

Comment: Just add it to your question, not to the comment

Comment: @Peter See my answer, change another properties the same way

Comment: I get the same error! But if you look at the error text again what I find weird is the fact it is expecting OASIS_MVC.Models.AnalysteMain] but is getting [OASIS_MVC.Models.Biredat2] , so is my query correctly coded? I see the data I expect when I look at result on DATA. The returned error is from select m, If I use Select s I get the same error type but with [OASIS_MVC.Models.Suivi] as the return. Its as if I'm not processing the return properly.

Comment: Can you post biredat2 class. I don't see how it is related to AnalysteMain class

Comment: And  I am sorry but I have answered your question already.  Pls, acceept it. You have more bugs then lines of code and I am not a personal instructor.  It can take a week to fix all of them. Make a new post about how to get data from entity framework. You will have to post all your classes.

Comment: The real problem is that I put in biredat2 instead of AnalysteMain at this line. But I appreciated the way model was changed to model[0] for a list.